# Problems with plotting interpolating function derived from NDSolve`ProcessSolutions

Tags: differential-equations

1. I am trying a simple test of plotting an interpolating function derived from numerical solution to heat equation using NDSolve`ProcessEquations, NDSolve`Iterate and NDSolve`ProcessSolutions protocol. The error I am getting is as follows:

> Input value {0.0000408571,0.} lies outside the range of data in the 
> interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

Here is the simple code:

```
state = First[
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
 u[0, x] == Cos[\[Pi]/2 x], u[t, 0] == 1, u[t, 1] == 0}, u, 
t, {x, 0, 1}]];
NDSolve`Iterate[state, 2]
sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]
Table[Plot[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 2}], {x, 0, 1, 0.5}]
```

2. Furthermore, the domain in the interpolating function has only x varying from 0 to 1 while the time variable is still {0,0}. Why is that even after using NDSolve`Iterate?

Can you please help me out here? Thank you

Comment: You didn’t specify a domain for `t` in `ProcessEquations`.  Instead of `t` try, `{t, 0, 2}` or `{t, 0, Infinity}` if you wish to `Iterate` indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That solves the problem.
 I have yet another doubt on using the NDSolve`Reinitialize. 
I want to use the solution at time=N as initial condition for the time= N+1 to M and so on and so forth.
My doubt is how to  input the initial conditions for each differential equation?
thanks again